# Transitive dependency: override dependency does not works how expected

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-3

I am working with Maven and Spring.

I have many projects to be used how transitive dependencies for other projects.

I have the **01CentralDomainBasic** project

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
<artifactId>central-domain-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralDomainBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
```

It contains the *com.manuel.jordan.domain* package and some entities

I have the **01CentralRepositoryCommonBasic** project

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
<artifactId>central-repository-common-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralRepositoryCommonBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
…
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>                                           
</dependencies>
```

It contains the *com.manuel.jordan.model.repository* package and some repositories interfaces how ProductRepository. `(Only interface definitions)` They are implemented in other module/project.

I have the **01CentralRepositoryDataJpaBasic** project

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
<artifactId>central-repository-data-jpa-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralRepositoryDataJpaBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
…
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId> 
        <!-- Version handle through a <parent> -->
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

It contains the *com.manuel.jordan.model.repository* package and some repositories interfaces how ProductRepository. **Yes, same package and interfaces files names how the previous project** But remember that `(through Spring Data JPA, Spring implements the interface internally)` Therefore the content of each file is different. I don't need other module/project to make the implementation since Spring does that job for me.

I have the **01CentralServiceBasic** project

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
<artifactId>central-service-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralServiceBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
…
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It contains the *com.manuel.jordan.model.service* package and some *services* interfaces how ProductService. Again `(Only interface definitions)` They are implemented in other module/project (the following).

I have the **01CentralServiceImplBasic** project

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
<artifactId>central-service-impl-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralServiceImplBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
…
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-service-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-repository-common-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    …
</dependencies>
```

It depends and needs the service and repositories interfaces.

**Note**: repositories interfaces are need only for compilation purposes.

Now two final projects to be executed.

Project named **01HibernatePersistence**

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-persistence</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01HibernatePersistence</name>
…
<dependencies>
    …
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-repository-hibernate-impl-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-service-impl-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
    …
</dependencies>
```

Until here all works perfectly very well

The problem is with my **01DataJpaPersistence** project

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>data-jpa-persistence</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01DataJpaPersistence</name>
…
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-service-impl-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
                <artifactId>central-repository-common-basic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-repository-data-jpa-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The **central-service-impl-basic** needs the repository interface only for compilation purposes, it could be **central-repository-common-basic** or **central-repository-data-jpa-basic**, I have chosen the **central-repository-common-basic**.

In the previous code **central-repository-common-basic** is excluded and **central-repository-data-jpa-basic** is used (it has the same package and interface files **and** Spring makes internally the respective implementation behind the scenes).

Therefore:

- same `<groupId>` (com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository)
- different `<artifactId>` ( central-repository-common-basic and central-repository-data-jpa- basic)
- same `java package` (com.manuel.jordan.model.repository)
- same `ProductRepository` interface but of course with different content

But it doesn't works, I receive the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.manuel.jordan.model.repository.ProductRepository.save
(Lcom/manuel/jordan/domain/Product;)Lcom/manuel/jordan/domain/Product;
at 
com.manuel.jordan.model.service.impl.ProductServiceImpl.save(ProductServiceImpl.java:45)
```

If I do **dependency:tree** I get

```
[INFO] +- com.manuel.jordan.centralfactory:central-factory-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain:central-domain-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.manuel.jordan.centralservice:central-service-impl-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.manuel.jordan.centralservice:central-service-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |     \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
[INFO] +- com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository:central-repository-data-jpa-basic:jar:01:compile
```

The exclusion works how expected, the other expected dependency remains and appears but according with the error stack trace seems it has been ignored.

What is missing?

Thanks in advance

**Omicron**

The **01CentralRepositoryCommonBasic** project has

```
package com.manuel.jordan.model.repository;

import java.util.List;

import com.manuel.jordan.domain.Product;

public interface ProductRepository {

    Product save(Product product);

    Product findOne(Integer id);
    Long count();
    List<Product> findAll();

    Product update(Product product);

    void delete(Integer id);
    void delete(Product product);

}
```

The **01CentralRepositoryDataJpaBasic** project has

```
package com.manuel.jordan.model.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.manuel.jordan.domain.Product;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {

}
```

Again same package and same interface, but different content.

The **01CentralServiceImplBasic** project has

```
package com.manuel.jordan.model.service.impl;

…    
import com.manuel.jordan.model.repository.ProductRepository;

@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
@Service("productService")
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private ProductRepository productRepository; 

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository productRepository){
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }
```

How you can see, this service class only depends on the **ProductRepository**.

Other projects, again for example:

- 01HibernatePersistence, depends of other module/project named 01CentralRepositoryHibernateImplBasic, of course it implements the interface from the 01CentralRepositoryCommonBasic project (the pom.xml already has been shared above)
- 01DataJpaPersistence, it **does not depends** of other module/project since Spring does the implementation directly behind the scenes (the pom.xml already has been shared above).

Comment: Have you checked the scopes of you dependencies? Runtime VS compile

Comment: How do your application contexts in Spring look like?

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you split out your interfaces into a separate module, and swap the implementations? It's unusual to swap out your interfaces, and could lead to problems. Oh, you have a problem? See...

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to depend on transitive dependencies. If you use a library directly in your code, you should reference it in the closest pom.

Comment: Hannes: Yes, I have tested with <scope>provided</scope> and <scope>runtime</scope>, compile is used by default.

Comment: sorencito: all is about JavaConfig, it works fine.

Comment: Engineer Dollery: check **omicron** section. What do you mean with "If you use a library directly in your code, you should reference it in the closest pom". I don't understand.

Comment: If the module `central-service-impl-basic` is really an interface only (i would call it -api instead of -impl-` than it should never has a dependency to an implementation only the other way around.

Comment: No, central-service-impl-basic is for implementation and it depends on central-service-basic (only for interface definitions) both for services business.